# Converting Float to String without Truncating leading or trailing zeros

Tags: string, xlrd, zipcode, floating-point-conversion

I'm trying to extract Zip Codes from an Excel Spreadsheet and load them into a list as Strings.

```
import xlrd
BIL = xlrd.open_workbook(r"C:\Temp\Stores.xls)    
Worksheet = BIL.sheet_by_name("Open_Locations")
ZIPs = []
for record in Worksheet.col(17):
    if record.value == "Zip":
        pass
    else:
        ZIPs.append(record.value)
```

Unfortunately, this Excel workbook is managed by someone else so I cannot simply go and convert the field holding zip codes in the excel spreadsheet to text to solve my problem. In addition, believe it or not, this Excel spreadsheet also is used by some business intelligence systems. So changing that field from number to String could cause problems for other workflows leveraging this workbook, which I am not privy to.

What I'm finding is that when I print the numbers as they are without casting to integer or string first, I of course get a bunch of floats. I expected that, since Excel stores numbers as floats.

```
>>>Zips
[u'06405',
 04650.0,
 10017.0,
 71055.0,
 70801.0]
```

What I didn't expect is that when I cast these floats as int to get rid of the decimal values, then cast the result of that as string the result is that any leading or trailing zero which are part of the zip code value are truncated.

```
import xlrd
BIL = xlrd.open_workbook(r"C:\Temp\Stores.xls)    
Worksheet = BIL.sheet_by_name("Open_Locations")
ZIPs = []
for record in Worksheet.col(17):
    if record.value == "Zip":
        pass
    else:
        ZIPs.append(str(int(record.value)))

>>>Zips
['6405',
 '465',
 '10017',
 '71055',
 '70801']
```

How can I convert these zip codes to string without dropping the leading or trailing zeros or determine the number of leading and trailing zeros on the value prior to truncation and append them back as appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

All ZIP codes (not including the Zip+4) are 5 characters so you could just pad out to 5:

C#

- Use the String.Pad left method:
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- `ZIPs.append(str.PadLeft(5, '0');`

Python:

- Use rjust: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rjust.htm
- `ZIPs.append(str(int(record.value)).rjust(5, '0'))`

Comment: Thanks Al. rjust() would append any zeros to the beginning of the zip converting a zip of 06405 which is truncated to 6405 back to 06405. However, if there are both leading and trailing zeros truncated as occurs with a zip code such as 04650 truncating to 465, using rjust() would return a value of 00465, a completely different result from the original zip. The key seems to be determining how many leading or trailing zeros there are in the zip and then padding zeros onto both ends as appropriate. I've amended to question's zip examples to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

So after some tinkering, it turned out the answer was to:

1. Not cast the zip code as an int since this will also truncate any
   leading zeros
2. Explicitly encode the string as utf-8

The presence of the unicode string indicator tipped me off that this might be the answer when it appeared on some values but not all when I printed the list

```
for record in Worksheet.col(17):
    if record.value == "Zip":
        pass
    else:
        # In this case, the value is still being returned as float, because                          
        it has 1 significant digit of 0 appended to the end. So we'll cast 
        as string and explicitly encode it as utf-8 which will retain the 
        leading and trailing zeros of the value and also truncate the 
        significant digits via index.
        if len(str(record.value).encode('utf-8')) > 5 
            ZIPs.append(str(record.value).encode('utf-8'))
        else:
            # In this case, the value is already being returned as a unicode 
            string for some reason, probably because of poor excel worksheet 
            management, but in any case cast as string and explicitly encode 
            as utf-8 just for peace of mind.
            ZIPs.append(str(record.value).encode('utf-8'))

>>>Zips
   ['06405',
    '04650',
    '10017',
    '71055',
    '70801']
```

If anyone has a more elegant way of doing this, I would love to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this through string manipulation.

Our assumption here will be that the column will be ZIP codes, so '.0' at the end will never be necessary.

The below would go in your else statement:

```
record_str = str(record.value)
formatted_record = record_str[:-2] if record_str.endswith('.0') else record_str
ZIPs.append(formatted_record )
```

Or if you want to be risque our assumption here would be reading this column will always have a '.0' otherwise it can cause unexpected behavior.

```
ZIPs.append(str(record.value)[:-2])
```