# A variable containing a float: how to convert to string where trailing zeros are KEPT in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have a variable `K = 25.00` and I need to search a value in a dataframe column such as

```
data[f"Item {K}"][99]
```

but `K` reverts to `25.0` when turned into a string. 
Is there a nice way to make `K` stay `25.00` throughout?
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399533/converting-float-to-string-without-truncating-leading-or-trailing-zeros) but that method looks so messy, there must be a simpler way?

Comment: Describing your code isn't nearly as useful as _showing it_ to us. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] so we can better understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the modern Python 3 formatting:

```
data[f"Item {K:.2f}"][99]
```

Note that you shouldn't normally call variables 'K' but rather 'k', since the use of uppercase indicates a class type, not a variable.

As @Tushar already suggested, the above is equivalent to:

```
data["Item {:.2f}".format(Variable)][99]
```

But I do like the new Python 3 formatting.

Comment: Incidentally, you're right - padding with zeroes is definitely not the way to go here.